# Could not find or load main class cool

Tags: java

I got a java program that's used to parse a url, so i used jsoup to import the libs and i use classpath to point it
but i can't run a java program here, i compiled it, the class file is formed but it says " Could not find or load main class cool "

My program is given below
 PGM NAME IS : cool.java

I compiled it using this command : javac -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar cool.java
It compiles fine
But
 when i tried to run this with the below command

"java -cp  jsoup-1.8.3.jar cool"
it says the error "Could not find or load main class cool"

My program is given below

```
package com.mkyong;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

 public class cool {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Document doc;
try {

    // need http protocol
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();

    // get page title
    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);

    // get all links
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link : links) {

        // get the value from href attribute
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

 } }
```

I'm using ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a package. This means that your main class is called:

```
com.mykong.cool
```

So your propper command is:

```
java -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar com.mykong.cool
```

You could also remove your package declaration (the first line of your code)

Comment: package com.mkyong;

<-- This is your package declaration. Just change it to what you like. In this case your compiled file would be called com/mkyong/cool.class

Comment: Thanks for your help , i removed the first line , so now i have to compile the program with the command like this " java -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar cool" , then also  the error exists Error: Could not find or load main class cool

Answer (score 2):

> "java -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar cool" it says the error "Could not find or
>   load main class cool"

Since your class `cool` is in a package. So

**Compile:**

```
javac -d . cool.java
```

**Run:**

```
java com.mkyong.cool
```

See the package statement at first line of your class.

```
package com.mkyong;
```

Before you must set classpath to `jsoup-1.8.3.jar`.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class com.mkyong.cooljava , i did what you said, then this error is popped up , this is the command i typed in "java -cp jsoup-1.8.3.jar com.mykong.cool " ,

Comment: If you follow those two steps it should works @AkshaySasidharan

Comment: i know that you copied it from a site. No need of changing the package name. @AkshaySasidharan

Comment: Thanks for your help satya :)

Comment: wel come ;) @AkshaySasidharan

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the location of your `.class` file in your classpath.